# Inlining dynamic css style in JSX

Tags: css, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I have a hundred images which I want to add as a background to 100 **div** elements in my page.

I have a common style (**style**), and then I have the variable part which is the image. I use **Object.assign** to create *style1, style2, style3* etc, which merges the static with the variable part.

It looks something like this :

```
let style = {width:w, height:h, backgroundColor:'red', border :'5px solid red'}

let style1 = Object.assign(style, {backgroundImage:"url(" + img1 + ")"});
let style2 = Object.assign(style, {backgroundImage:"url(" + img2 + ")"});
....
let style100 = Object.assign(style, {backgroundImage:"url(" + img100 + ")"});


return (
  <div>
      <div style={style1}>1</div>
      <div style={style2}>2</div>
      <div style={style3}>3</div>

    ...

      <div style={style99}>99</div>
      <div style={style100}>100</div>
  </div>
);
```

This looks very ugly...

Is there an 'inline' way of doing this? Something like so :

```
<div style={Object.assign(style, {backgroundImage:"url(" + img1 + ")")}>1</div>
<div style={Object.assign(style, {backgroundImage:"url(" + img2 + ")")}>2</div>
```

Comment: At a glance, your code looks correct (the last part). Did you try it?

Comment: you know what? I didn't :) I was just guessing what a solution might look like :) I will try it now

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use a loop here, instead of declaring 100 styles and 100 images?

Comment: that part is correct, but there is a small hidden issue, issue is `Object.assign(style, ....)` will always update the style object also, instead of that either use `Object.assign({}, style, .....)` or `spread operator`. for more details check the [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: yes thank you that worked. I needed the {} as first argument to prevent overwriteing as Mayank stated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [proposal-object-rest-spread](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread) (you'll need babel's [Object rest spread transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/)) to merge the background image with the style object. In addition you can use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to inject the img dynamic part into the static part:

```
<div style={{ ...style, backgroundImage: `url(${img1})` }}>1</div>
```

btw - all of this should be done in a loop, probably using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and you might want to create a component for each image.

You'll have an array of images ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', etc...].

An image component would be something like this:

```
const Image = ({ style, img, text }) => (
    <div style={{ ...style, backgroundImage: `url(${img}.png)` }}>{text}</div>
);
```

And the outer component's render would probably look like this:

```
render() {
    const {images} = this.props;

    return (
        images.map((img, index) => (
            <Image style={style} img={img} text={index} key={img} />
        ))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A small addition to [**@OriDrori's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46322905/2315280) that you can also pass array of objects to style prop.

```
<div style={[style, { backgroundImage: `url(${img1})` }]}>1</div>
```

So this also means you can create a small function that can return an object with the correct background image

```
const getBackgroundImage = (image) => {
  return { backgroundImage: `url(${image})` };
}

<div style={[style, getBackgroundImage(img1)]}>1</div>
```