# How can I use conditional statements alongside inline styles correctly in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am building a pizza builder react application. An application where users can build pizzas in real-time and order them. I am trying to set some conditional styles based on the state and the input Handler but my styles are not being applied.

This is my JSX code

```
class PizzaBuilder extends Component {
  state = {
    sauce: {
      selected: 'Marinara'
    }
  }
  toggleSauceHandler = (type) => () => {
    this.setState({
      toggle: type
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className={styles.Sauce}>
        <div>
          <img style={this.state.toggle==="Marinara" ? {display: 'block', position: 'absolute', zIndex: '100'}: null} src={Marinara} alt="marinara" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="sauce" id="Marinara" value="Marinara" onChange={this.toggleSauceHandler( "Marinara")} checked={this.state.toggle==="Marinara" }/>
        <label for="Marinara">Marinara</label>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The Sauce itself is set to display none as I do not need the images showing on the page.  I only want to show the one by one based on the input from the radio button.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46322708/inlining-dynamic-css-style-in-jsx. It might help

Comment: It's called conditional rendering, and works like this: `{this.state.toggle === "Marinara" && <img .../>}`

Answer (score 0):

Check below link, may be helpful for you.

[React - Change Inline CSS Conditionally Based on Component State](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/react-change-inline-css-conditionally-based-on-component-state/199621)